# ActionBar Sherlock covers all screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have just implemented in my Android Application the Sherlock's ActionBar.

The issue is: as you can see from image, my SupportMapFragment of Google Maps API v2, loaded in the MainActivity, is completely overlayed by the actionBar. I have already done some tests: load a different fragment, for example a simple SherlockListFragment, but the result is absolutely the same, and to DON'T set the setListNavigationCallbacks (beacuse the problem could be my custom SpinnerAdapter) but the actionBar always covers all the screen, even without any text in it.

IMAGE:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0lnekjttdzv2xa/2012-12-18_14-45-43.png

Some Code from my app:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener 
{
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
private FragmentMappa fMappa;
private FragmentLinee fLinee;
private FragmentAtmInforma fAtm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fMappa = new FragmentMappa();
    fLinee = new FragmentLinee();
    fAtm = new FragmentAtmInforma();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int IdFixedHeader = -1;
    Utils.ImpostaActionBar(IdFixedHeader, this);

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(getListener());
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainContainer, fMappa).commit();
    new downloadUtils().execute(0, this, true);
}
```

Utils.java

```
public static void ImpostaActionBar(int IdFixedHeader, SherlockFragmentActivity Act, String StrFixHead) {
    // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
    ActionBar actionBar = Act.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ArrayList<VoceListaMenuNav> Voci = new ArrayList<VoceListaMenuNav>();
    Voci.add(new VoceListaMenuNav(Act.getString(R.string.title_mappa), R.drawable.btn_show_map));
    Voci.add(new VoceListaMenuNav(Act.getString(R.string.title_linee), R.drawable.btn_compass_tilt));   
    Voci.add(new VoceListaMenuNav(Act.getString(R.string.title_percorso), R.drawable.fer));
    Voci.add(new VoceListaMenuNav(Act.getString(R.string.title_preferiti), R.drawable.btn_show_map));
    Voci.add(new VoceListaMenuNav(Act.getString(R.string.title_AtmInforma), R.drawable.btn_show_map));
    // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(new AdapterListaMenuNav(Act.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), Voci, IdFixedHeader, StrFixHead), (OnNavigationListener) Act);
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(IdFixedHeader);
}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<color name="GrigioSemiTrasp">#af000000</color>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/GrigioSemiTrasp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

My custom adapter:

```
public class AdapterListaMenuNav extends BaseAdapter
{
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = arg1;
    if (rowView == null)
    {
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_menu_nav_top, null);
      ViewHolderListaGenerica viewHolder = new ViewHolderListaGenerica();
      viewHolder.Titolo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ListaMenuNavTitolo);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    if (FixedHeader == -1)
    {
        ViewHolderListaGenerica holder = (ViewHolderListaGenerica)rowView.getTag();
        VoceListaMenuNav f = LisVoci.get(arg0);
        holder.Titolo.setText(f.Titolo);
        return rowView;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewHolderListaGenerica holder = (ViewHolderListaGenerica)rowView.getTag();
        VoceListaMenuNav f = LisVoci.get(FixedHeader);
        holder.Titolo.setText(f.Titolo);
        return rowView;
    }
}

Context Ctx;
ArrayList<VoceListaMenuNav> LisVoci;
LayoutInflater inflater;
int FixedHeader;

public AdapterListaMenuNav(Context Cont, ArrayList<VoceListaMenuNav> ListaVoci, int IdFixedHeader, String StrFxHeader)
{
    LisVoci = ListaVoci;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)Cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Ctx = Cont;
    FixedHeader = IdFixedHeader;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return LisVoci.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View rowView = arg1;
    if (rowView == null)
    {
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_menu_nav, null);
      ViewHolderListaGenerica viewHolder = new ViewHolderListaGenerica();
      viewHolder.Titolo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ListaMenuNavTitolo);
      viewHolder.Immagine = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ListaMenuNavImage);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolderListaGenerica holder = (ViewHolderListaGenerica)rowView.getTag();
    VoceListaMenuNav f = LisVoci.get(arg0);
    holder.Titolo.setText(f.Titolo);
    holder.Immagine.setImageResource(f.IdImage);
    return rowView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled to find out anything and finally can answer myself. The problem was from WHAT the ABS style was inheriting from. The correct code is:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
....
</style>
```